# Is SQL Server Express ANSI compliant?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Can you run ANSI SQL statements in SQL Server Express 2005 or 2008?

Comment: See Brian's answer below and in case there's any ambiguity in your mind, Express editions function the same as the "full" editions with respect to pretty much anything on the core database and TSQL side except how big the db can get.

Answer (score 3):

Sql Server understands Ansi Sql. However there are always different interpretations of the standards. Here is an article that I found that lists some of the differences: [Think ANSI Standard SQL Is Fully Portable Between Databases? Think Again.](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/32852)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using SQL Server backends for your product, forget about ANSII sql, T-SQL has much more efficient and effective ways of querying a SQL Server database. ANSII is ok if you have to have a multiple backends, but if you don't it is stupid to limit yourself to the least effective code available. This is true of any database backend, the proprietary language for that database is designed to run better than anything else.

But in answer to your question, yes some of the ANSII standard works and some of it does not. For any basic queries you may be ok, it is the complex stuff which tends to really point out the differences. So basically you can't get out of testing it all. Which you should be doing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is only partially ANSI compliant. The biggest difference is the string concatenation operator which should be `||` but is `+` in SQL Server.

Additionally depending on the collation of the current database it might not comply with the case-sensitivity rules required by the standard.

Other (I think required) ANSI features that are missing:

- no ANSI date/time literals (`DATE '2012-08-28'`, `TIMESTAMP '2012-08-28 17:33:05'`)
- no interval datatype
- The row constructor `VALUES` (outside of the `INSERT` clause)
- No tuple comparison `(col1, col2) = (1,2)`
- `NULLS FIRST/LAST` option for `ORDER BY`

Most of the missing features have some non-standard equivalent in T-SQL though.

The SQL standard is a nice thing and if I have a choice between two SQL constructs I choose the standard one over the non-standard one.

But writing DBMS-independent applications is simply not going to work (well) - at least not for non-trivial applications.

If it is truly DBMS independent it merely means it will be equally slow on all DBMS.

You paid a lot of cash for all SQL Server features (or not so much for SQL Server Express) so go use them.